# How can I detect specific sound from live application?

Tags: python, audio, automation

Is there a way to collect live audio from application (like chrome, mozilla) and execute some code 
when a specific sound is played on website ?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but without you showing us an effort you made and asking a more specific question about trouble you're having with it, this is not a suitable SO question.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a mic on whatever device you are using, you can use that to read whatever sound  is coming out of your computer. Then, you can compare those audio frames that you are recording to a sound file of what sound you are looking for

Of course, this leaves it very vulnerable to background noise, so somehow you are going to have to filter it out.

Here is an example using the PyAudio and wave libraries:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

wf = wave.open("websitSound.wav", "rb")
amountFrames = 100 # just an arbitrary number; could be anything
sframes = wf.readframes(amountFrames)

currentSoundFrame = 0

chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
channels = 2
fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second
seconds = 3

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio


stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                channels=channels,
                rate=fs,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                input=True)


# Store data in chunks for 3 seconds
for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    if data == sframes[currentSoundFrame]:
        currentSoundFrame += 1
        if currentSoundFrame == len(sframes): #the whole entire sound was played
            print("Sound was played!")
    frames.append(data)

# Stop and close the stream 
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
# Terminate the PortAudio interface
p.terminate()
```